# get process name from process id (win32)

Tags: c, winapi, process, pid

I need to get a list of all processes on a windows system including names and PID.
[EnumProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can obtain a list of pids, but how do I get the process name from the pid? I don't want to call OpenProcess on the process as that doesn't always work (like if the other process is run by a different user).

Comment: I don't think you can reliably do this on Windows versions after Vista. Which version are you using?

Comment: you could possibly use WMI for this

Comment: What do you mean by process name - the EXE name?

Answer (score 18):

You have different option which you can use to receive exe names of currently running processes (process names like you wrote). The best way depends a little from the programming language which you use and from other requirements. For example you can use WMI. One other more old way is the usage of [Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083(VS.85).aspx) (see also [An Introduction To Performance Counters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/perfcounter.aspx)). To get the counters values you can just use registry query operations from the `HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA` base key (see [Retrieving Counter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373178(VS.85).aspx))

One more way which can be also good used is the [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509(VS.85).aspx) function with `SystemProcessInformation` as a parameter. `EnumProcess` and many other Windows API use the function internally. The struct `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` defined in the documentation of [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509(VS.85).aspx) has many "undocumented" but since many many years well-known fields. If you search in the Internet for the definition of the structure you will fined full documentation. I wonder that the function hat status not full documented. The function was at least in NT 3.5 (probably also before) and can be good used now on Windows 7 32- or 64-bit. To be exact below you will find a small C test program which print all process ids with the corresponding exe names (not full exe path, just the file name):

```
#include <Windows.h>
// one can also use Winternl.h if needed
//#include <Winternl.h> // for UNICODE_STRING and SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define STATUS_SUCCESS               ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L)
#define STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH  ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000004L)

typedef enum _SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    SystemProcessInformation = 5
} SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING;

typedef LONG KPRIORITY; // Thread priority

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi1;
    LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi2;
    LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi3;
    LARGE_INTEGER CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    KPRIORITY BasePriority;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    ULONG InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
    ULONG HandleCount;
    BYTE Reserved4[4];
    PVOID Reserved5[11];
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER Reserved6[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD;

typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)(
  IN       SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass,
  IN OUT   PVOID SystemInformation,
  IN       ULONG SystemInformationLength,
  OUT OPTIONAL  PULONG ReturnLength
);

int main()
{
    size_t bufferSize = 102400;
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD pspid=
        (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD) malloc (bufferSize);
    ULONG ReturnLength;
    PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION pfnNtQuerySystemInformation = (PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)
        GetProcAddress (GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    NTSTATUS status;

    while (TRUE) {
        status = pfnNtQuerySystemInformation (SystemProcessInformation, (PVOID)pspid,
                                              bufferSize, &ReturnLength);
        if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
            break;
        else if (status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) { // 0xC0000004L
            _tprintf (TEXT("ERROR 0x%X\n"), status);
            return 1;   // error
        }

        bufferSize *= 2;
        pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD) realloc ((PVOID)pspid, bufferSize);
    }

    for (;;
         pspid=(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)(pspid->NextEntryOffset + (PBYTE)pspid)) {

        _tprintf (TEXT("ProcessId: %d, ImageFileName: %ls\n"), pspid->UniqueProcessId,
            (pspid->ImageName.Length && pspid->ImageName.Buffer)? pspid->ImageName.Buffer: L"");

        if (pspid->NextEntryOffset == 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Saved me a lot of time. Just a side note: there's a memory leak where you're not freeing up "pspid". Still awesome though :-)

Comment: It's very easy to "fix" the memory leak. It's really needed only of you use the code as a part of function. To do this you need just save the value of `pspid` after the first loop in another variable (because in the current code the value will be modified) and call `free` with the pointer.

Answer (score 18):

Ýou can get the process identifier and `name` for all running processes using the [ToolHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686840%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API.
The following code will display the `pid` and `name` for each process.

```
void showProcessInformation() {
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if(hSnapshot) {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
        pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
        if(Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe32)) {
            do {
               printf("pid %d %s\n", pe32.th32ProcessID, pe32.szExeFile);
            } while(Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32));
         }
         CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
}
```

Comment: you just need to use: 
pe32.dwSize=sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); before calling Process32First()

Comment: This is really cool and much faster then the `NtQuerySystemInformation` technique. Is there any way to get the PID creation time though with this technique?

Comment: @Noitidart - I guess you could open a process using `hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);` and then use `GetProcessTimes()` to get the needed information

Comment: @Noitidart - I think you also need to enable `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` for the process using a combination of `OpenProcessToken()` and `SetPrivilege()` etc

Comment: Thanks much @Cyclone for that info, I think it might be more efficient to call `NtQuerySystemInformation` then no?

Answer (score 5):

CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() will give you the process name (but not the path); other than that, you will have to call OpenProcess().  If your code is running in an administrative context you could enable the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege to get access to processes running under other contexts.