# C++ - Process infos

Tags: c++, process

I am writing a cross-platform program which requires simple information on the running program: `process name`, `process id`, `thread id`.

The `process id` and `thread id` are simple to get on each platform, using pre-processor directives should do it.

But for the `process name`, I looked over the internet and I didnt find anything easy and a bit cross-platform which is not that surprising. Since I am writting a library which must be extremely simple to use, I don't have access to `argv[0]` which is exactly what I want.

I would like to know if someone had an easy way to do it ? This feature is not implemented in the official boost version.. unfortunately :(

Comment: *"using pre-processor directives should do it"* -- What does this mean?

Comment: #ifndef _WIN32 /* Linux treatment */ #else /* Win treatment */ #endif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I doubt you will find a nice cross-platform solution.
Most likely you will end up having some platform specific code within `#ifdef`'s.

Linux standard way is looking into `/proc` and parsing the results.
Windows way is using it's [sick API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102569/get-process-name-from-process-id-win32).

Comment: Thank you, I think I might do this. I hope boost will cover it very soon.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement @Andrejs Cainikovs' answer, the Windows solution is a simple call to `GetModuleFileName(NULL, charBuffer, elementCount)`: