# Decrypt WEP wlan profile key using CryptUnprotectData

Tags: c, windows-vista, encryption, wlanapi, wep

I am trying to decrypt WEP profile's key using [CryptUnprotectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The way I fetched the profile key is by exporting the profile using netsh.

```
netsh wlan export profile name="MyWEP" folder="./"
```

For now, I manually copied the key material from the .xml file generated by the netsh command to my program. And the way, I am decrypting is -

```
DATA_BLOB DataOut, DataVerify;
DataOut.cbData = encryptData.length();
DataOut.pbData = (BYTE*)("I_Manually_Copy_The_WEP_Key_Here");

if (CryptUnprotectData( &DataOut,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        0,
                        &DataVerify))
{
    printf("The decrypted data is: %s\n", DataVerify.pbData);
}
else
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code: %d", GetLastError());
}
```

But I am getting the error code **13** citing Invalid Data. What am I doing wrong ? On Win 7 and later, I can directly use [WlanGetProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the parameter **WLAN_PROFILE_GET_PLAINTEXT_KEY** . But I have **NO** option on **Vista** than to use the CryptUnprotectData function. I have seen similar posts [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vistawirelesssdk/thread/ad10453a-68a8-4f69-bcc8-76aeae9085f7), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/7815b530-65e7-4404-888a-02d929439094/) but didn't get much useful information. Also, I am using the same system with same user log on credentials. Could any one please suggest me how to proceed ?

PS: I have posted the same question on Windows Desktop SDK forums, but haven't got response yet. Trying my luck on SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like questions about Windows Security. So if I occasionally see such one I try to solve it.

In your case you did already the first step by the usage of `netsh.exe wlan export profile ...` to export the data from the WLAN profile in XML file. The file contains `<keyMaterial>` element. The data inside of the element are binary data encoded as the Hex: (something like `01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C0...`).

So what you need to do first of all is to decode the string to binary data. You can use [CryptStringToBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `CRYPT_STRING_HEX` parameter to decode the string to binary.

The next step will be to fill `DATA_BLOB` with the binary data and call `CryptUnprotectData` to get the result, but... There are small problem. How you can read in the documentation of [WlanGetProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the following

> By default, the **keyMaterial** element returned in the profile pointed to
>   by the *pstrProfileXml* is encrypted. If your process runs in the
>   context of the **LocalSystem** account on the same computer, then you can
>   unencrypt key material by calling the **CryptUnprotectData** function.
>
> **Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista**:  The **keyMaterial** element
>   returned in the profile schema pointed to by the *pstrProfileXml* is
>   always encrypted. If your process runs in the context of the
>   **LocalSystem** account, then you can unencrypt key material by calling
>   the **CryptUnprotectData** function.

So to be able to unencrypt the key we have to call [CryptUnprotectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in **LocalSystem** security context. If your program already run under **LocalSystem** context you can do this directly. If it's not so, but you have administrative rights or you have at least Debug privilege, you can "to borrow" the **LocalSystem** token from some other process running on the computer. For example one can get the process token of "winlogon.exe" process and impersonate it.

The following demo program enumerate processes using [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method (see my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110741/315935)) which I personally prefer. One can use [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or other well-known ways to do the same. Here is the code which worked at me

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Crypt32.lib")

#define STATUS_SUCCESS               ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L)
#define STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH  ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000004L)

typedef enum _SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS {
    SystemProcessInformation = 5
} SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING;

typedef LONG KPRIORITY; // Thread priority

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi1;
    LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi2;
    LARGE_INTEGER SpareLi3;
    LARGE_INTEGER CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    KPRIORITY BasePriority;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    ULONG InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
    ULONG HandleCount;
    BYTE Reserved4[4];
    PVOID Reserved5[11];
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER Reserved6[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD;

typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)(
  IN       SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass,
  IN OUT   PVOID SystemInformation,
  IN       ULONG SystemInformationLength,
  OUT OPTIONAL  PULONG ReturnLength
);

//
// The function changes a privilege named pszPrivilege for
// the current process. If bEnablePrivilege is FALSE, the privilege
// will be disabled, otherwise it will be enabled.
//
BOOL SetCurrentPrivilege (LPCTSTR pszPrivilege,   // Privilege to enable/disable
                          BOOL bEnablePrivilege)  // to enable or disable privilege
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tpPrevious;
    DWORD cbPrevious = sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES);
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, pszPrivilege, &luid)) return FALSE;

    if (!OpenProcessToken (GetCurrentProcess(),
                           TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
                           &hToken
                          )) return FALSE;

    //
    // first pass.  get current privilege setting
    //
    tp.PrivilegeCount           = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid       = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(
            hToken,
            FALSE,
            &tp,
            sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
            &tpPrevious,
            &cbPrevious);

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        //
        // second pass.  set privilege based on previous setting
        //
        tpPrevious.PrivilegeCount     = 1;
        tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;

        if(bEnablePrivilege)
            tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes |= (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED);
        else
            tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes ^= (SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED &
                tpPrevious.Privileges[0].Attributes);

        AdjustTokenPrivileges(
                hToken,
                FALSE,
                &tpPrevious,
                cbPrevious,
                NULL,
                NULL);

        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_SUCCESS) bSuccess=TRUE;

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    else {
        DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();

        CloseHandle(hToken);
        SetLastError(dwErrorCode);
    }

    return bSuccess;
}

DWORD GetProcessIdByProcessName (LPCWSTR pszProcessName)
{
    SIZE_T bufferSize = 1024*sizeof(SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD);
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD pspid = NULL;
    HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
    PBYTE pBuffer = NULL;
    ULONG ReturnLength;
    PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION pfnNtQuerySystemInformation = (PFN_NT_QUERY_SYSTEM_INFORMATION)
        GetProcAddress (GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll")), "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    NTSTATUS status;
    int uLen = lstrlenW(pszProcessName)*sizeof(WCHAR);

    __try {
        pBuffer = (PBYTE) HeapAlloc (hHeap, 0, bufferSize);
#pragma warning(disable: 4127)
        while (TRUE) {
#pragma warning(default: 4127)
            status = pfnNtQuerySystemInformation (SystemProcessInformation, (PVOID)pBuffer,
                                                  bufferSize, &ReturnLength);
            if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
                break;
            else if (status != STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH) { // 0xC0000004L
                _tprintf (TEXT("ERROR 0x%X\n"), status);
                return 1;   // error
            }

            bufferSize *= 2;
            pBuffer = (PBYTE) HeapReAlloc (hHeap, 0, (PVOID)pBuffer, bufferSize);
        }

        for (pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)pBuffer; ;
             pspid = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION_DETAILD)(pspid->NextEntryOffset + (PBYTE)pspid)) {

            if (pspid->ImageName.Length == uLen && lstrcmpiW(pspid->ImageName.Buffer, pszProcessName) == 0)
                return (DWORD)pspid->UniqueProcessId;

            if (pspid->NextEntryOffset == 0) break;
        }
    }
    __finally {
        pBuffer = (PBYTE) HeapFree (hHeap, 0, pBuffer);
    }
    return 0;
}

int _tmain()
{
    BOOL bIsSuccess, bImpersonated = FALSE;
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL, hProcessToken = NULL;
    DATA_BLOB DataOut, DataVerify;
    // !!! in the next line you should copy the string from <keyMaterial>
    WCHAR szKey[] = L"01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7....";
    BYTE byKey[1024];
    DWORD cbBinary, dwFlags, dwSkip;
    DWORD dwProcessId = GetProcessIdByProcessName(L"winlogon.exe");
    if (dwProcessId == 0) return 1;

    bIsSuccess = SetCurrentPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);
    if (!bIsSuccess) return GetLastError();

    __try {
        hProcess = OpenProcess(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, FALSE, dwProcessId);
        if (!hProcess) __leave;
        bIsSuccess = OpenProcessToken (hProcess, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &hProcessToken);
        if (!bIsSuccess) __leave;
        bIsSuccess = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hProcessToken);
        if (!bIsSuccess) __leave;
        bImpersonated = TRUE;

        cbBinary = sizeof(byKey);
        bIsSuccess = CryptStringToBinary (szKey, lstrlenW(szKey), CRYPT_STRING_HEX, // CRYPT_STRING_HEX_ANY
            byKey, &cbBinary, &dwSkip, &dwFlags);
        if (!bIsSuccess) __leave;
        DataOut.cbData = cbBinary;
        DataOut.pbData = (BYTE*)byKey;

        if (CryptUnprotectData (&DataOut, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &DataVerify)) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("The decrypted data is: %hs\n"), DataVerify.pbData);
        }
    }
    __finally {
        if (bImpersonated)
            RevertToSelf();
        if (hProcess)
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        if (hProcessToken)
            CloseHandle(hProcessToken);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. The code is working fine for all networks and partially for a WEP network. While fetching the key of WEP network, `DataVerify.pbData` has garbage value at at the end ( `LLLMEM+`, this value is consistent ). How ever, `DataVerify.cbData` is showing the length of the key correctly. Can you please check whether the same is happening on your machine too ? I am using VS 2010.

Comment: I manually added a WEP type network at **Network and Sharing Center -> Manage Wireless Networks**. Once again, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I never cared for the term **LocalSystem** because I was running as **Administrator** and was under the impression that **Administrator** is more like a super user and can do anything.

Comment: @Mahesh: You are right! The data from `DataVerify.pbData` must be not NULL terminated. So one should fix the line `_tprintf(TEXT("The decrypted data is: %hs\n"), DataVerify.pbData);` to display only `DataVerify.cbData` bytes of data. One can use for example `_tprintf(TEXT("The decrypted data is: %*hs\n"), DataVerify.cbData,  DataVerify.pbData);` or just copy the string data and append there with `\0`.

Comment: Ok. Many many thanks. You got my job done. Thanks for the code :)

Comment: @Mahesh: I see that it's your first question where you used bounty. So I'm not sure whether you know how it works. If you plan to award the bounty you have to do this explicitly (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/147495) for more information).

Comment: Now I see you are rewarded 200. I thought by accepting the answer, the bounty will be rewarded automatically.

Comment: @Mahesh: It works not so intuitive, but it's not a problem. Best wishes!

Comment: What made you think that the binary data should be passed to `CryptUnProtectData` ? MSDN neither specified it. Is it just by your experience or did I miss something from MSDN ? Just curious.

Comment: @Mahesh: The input parameter has the type `DATA_BLOB` and not something like `LPWSTR`. So the input data have binary type. It's *encrypted* data, so it's typical that the data are *binary*.

Comment: Is this Python? Or how do I use this code on windows?

Comment: @Sonalk: The code is written in C. The answer is old, but I tried it once more and it still works. You need to start "netsh.exe wlan export profile" as admin to export WLAN profiles in files, get <keyMaterial> value from an exported file and place in my code as the value of szKey variable. Then you need compile the code in Visual Studio fo example and start the program with admin rights. The program will display decrypted value of the WLAN key. It's easy to modify the code to enter szKey via command line parameters.

Comment: @Sonalk: One can use code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlangetprofile?redirectedfrom=MSDN to get the <keyMaterial> instead of usage "netsh.exe wlan export profile"