# How can i know thread name for PDH from thread id

Tags: c++, winapi, pdh

I need to check `context switches` for thread. I'm writing function, that return `context switches` from thread id. I'm computing context switch counts using the PDH library. I can get the thread context switch count for all threads using this construction:

```
Status = PdhAddCounter(Query, resultBuffer, NULL, &Counter);
```

where `resultBuffer` is `"Thread(_Total/_Total)\\Context Switches/sec"`

What do I have to change `(_Total/_Total)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some playing around with perfmon suggests that the format should be

```
Thread(<process name>/<thread id>)\\Context Switches/sec
```

The thread ID you already have; you can get the process name from the process ID using the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102569/get-process-name-from-process-id-win32).