# Get the running processes which established a TCP connection in C++

Tags: c++, tcp, process

How can I get the running processes which established a TCP connection in C++?

I know about Process::GetProcesses() function.

But how can I short list those processes which established a TCP connection.

Any property in Process class describe this.?

Comment: *"I know about Process::GetProcesses() function."* - perhaps, but we don't - it's not a C++ Standard Library class/function.  You should specify *which library* you're using if you want advice on it, since there are doubtless many libraries with a `Process` class or namespace, and might be a few of those with `GetProcesses()` functions....

Comment: I just decided to use MFC ...
Is there any classes which can provide me the details..

Answer (score 3):

If on windows system you need to use IPhelper apis

[GetTcpTable2()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yes, this should get you process ids for all the processes which have any tcp connections

Comment: yes I tried it.. Actually it gave me all TCP connections and process IDs now I want the Process names of those corresponding PIDs..

That is My requirement

Comment: Did you try this [Process name from process id] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102569/get-process-name-from-process-id-win32/)